# Winforms Combobox Displaymember not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

This is probably a non-issue but I am kind of deperate at the moment.

I Have a WinForms application with several comboboxes. And they all work fine except one.
When I select an item from one box, I want to load lists as a datasource to several other lists. That works fine except the one combobox doesnt show the displaymember but the object name.

```
public void OnSelectedValueChanged()
    {
        ModelUser = _mainView.cboUserList.SelectedItem as ModelUser;

        if (ModelUser != null)
        {
            _mainView.cboUserComputers.DataSource = ModelUser.ComputerList;
            _mainView.cboUserComputers.DisplayMember = "Name";

            _mainView.cboComputerList.DataSource = ModelUser.ComputerList;
            _mainView.cboComputerList.DisplayMember = "Name";

        }
    }
```

I've set the datasources to the same list now to make sure there is no problem with the list itself.
The first combobox `cboUserComputers` shows everything correct. When I open the combobox, I get all the computer names.
The second combobox `cboComputerList`shows only the 'object names', I get a list of `MyProject.Models.ModelComputer`. Once I select an item, it shows the name correctly.

I've looked for hours but can't find anything. Help?

Comment: Isn't your comboBox populated/used in any other part of your program? Something similar happened to me with a DataGridView, it worked on a "test app" (where I only had the dgv and the function I needed for it) but it didn't work in my "main app", where there were other functions messing it up. Try putting a breakpoint or messagebox immediately after you populate it, to see if it is ok at that point. If it is ok it means something the compiler does later is messing your control.

Comment: Have you tried setting the DisplayMember before you set the DataSource?

Comment: @HandbagCrab I have tried that, but it made no difference

Comment: @GabrielStancu I load several textboxes with information from the selected `ModelComputer` object. All information, including the name seems to be there.

Comment: What I meant was that the specific comboBox that is not working might be used later by your code and that might be wrong only with that specific comboBox

Comment: @GabrielStancu No, once it is populated, I only use it to read the selected item

Comment: @GabrielStancu I finally found a solution. I deleted the combobox and created a new one with exactly the same settings and name. Now everything works fine. Looks like the first combobox was somehow broken -.-

Comment: Great to hear that, I would have suggested that but I thought you had already tryed that ^^